# Install Kafka with sbt in an isolated environment

Tags: sbt, apache-kafka, rpm, yum, rhel6

I'm trying to install Kafka, on RHEL 6.6, with the following [instructions](http://kafka.apache.org/07/quickstart.html):

```
> tar xzf kafka-<VERSION>.tgz
> cd kafka-<VERSION>
> ./sbt update
> ./sbt package
```

When installing `sbt` with `yum install sbt-0.13.9.rpm` from the [bintray rpm repository](https://bintray.com/sbt/rpm) everything goes fine but then when trying to execute `sbt` commands I get alway the following error:

```
root@servername:/# sbt
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.9 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9

        ==== local: tried

          /root/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/ivys/ivy.xml

          -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9!sbt.jar:

          /root/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/jars/sbt.jar

        ==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried

          http://nexus-bp2s.is.echonet/content/groups/public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.pom

          -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9!sbt.jar:

          http://nexus-bp2s.is.echonet/content/groups/public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /root/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt
```

The biggest problem is that I need to make it work in a closed intranet environment.

I already tried to add our nexus proxy as the maven repository but still, doesn't work.

***So the big question is how can I install `sbt` completely local (no need for it to connect anywhere)? Or is there an alternative to install Kafka in RHEL 6.6? And how?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you ended up on the instructions for possibly the oldest Kafka version (v0.7) still out there, which was released in 2012. :-)

> So the big question is how can I install sbt completely local (no need for it to connect anywhere)?

Nowadays Kafka doesn't even use `sbt` anymore, so there's no need to install sbt anywhere (and no need for it to connect anywhere).

Instead, follow the latest instructions at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_download:

> [Download](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/0.10.0.0/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.tgz) the 0.10.0.1 release and un-tar it.
>
> ```
> $ tar -xzf kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.tgz
> $ cd kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1
> ```

That's it.  You don't need to do any `sbt update` calls etc.

> Or is there an alternative to install Kafka in RHEL 6.6? And how?

If you prefer ready-to-use RPMs for installing on RHEL 6 (so you can use `yum install ...`, or Puppet, Ansible, ...), you may want to take a look at http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.1/installation.html#installation-yum.

PS: Or are you really trying to install Kafka 0.7?  Unless you have a very special/good reason to do that, I'd definitely recommend to not touch it and instead go with the most stable release, which is Kafka 0.10.0.

Comment: No, I'm using one of the 0.10.x versions, but in the instructions they mention using sbt to compile it.

Comment: @CMPSoares: Where do you find these sbt instructions? There are nowhere in the Apache Kafka docs at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html.

Comment: Searching Google... xD